# How to create link relation for POST end point?

Tags: rest, hyperlink, hateoas

While building a RESTful API of my web service I'm trying to give clients [link relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_relation), for example (this is what a GET entry point returns):

```
<doc>
 <links>
  <link rel="self" href="/home"/>
  <link rel="post" href="/post-new-article"/>
 </links>
</doc>
```

I'm expecting the client to understand that in order to post a new article he has to submit a POST request to `/post-new-article` with `"text"` as query parameter.

But I didn't say anything about `"POST"` in the document, and I didn't tell him which HTTP query parameter I'm expecting. How and where should I provide this information? Is there any de-facto standard/convention about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technically correct answer is that it is defined by the media type of the document.  For example, assume the API serves HTML.  And the client is a browser.

By convention, when a user-agent (browser) visits a resource (identified by an anchor tag) it issues an HTTP `GET` to the server serving the API.  Assuming everything goes as planned, the server returns another HTML representation of that resource.

Likewise, when a user-agent submits a form it issues an HTTP `GET` by default unless the `method` attribute of the `form` tag indicates it should `POST` the data.  (Details [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3).)

Your API documentation should specify in detail the media type your REST service uses.  If it is a custom type then the specification should include the rules for following links.  If your API runs over HTTP, then the rules would specify `GET`, `POST`, `DELETE`, etc. as well as any other requirements/conventions.

From Roy himself: http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven